# Toolbar should be over the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm facing an issue. I implemented an `AVPlayer` and it works. But if the video is in 4:3 format, the `UIToolBar` which i've implemented in the view, the video view is over my toolbar, so i cannot use the buttons. How i can set that the `UIToolBar` is always over this view. The toolbar style should be `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write Simple:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourToolBar];
```